# Sharepoint web.config deployment

Tags: deployment, web-config

I have SharePoint app which we are deploying to another SharePoint server and I need to update target server web.config with changes made on source server web.config. Can somebody advise me how to perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" 

#connect to the function library for this script 
$functionLocation = "C:\PowerShell\WebConfigModifications" 
. $functionLocation\Web_Config_Modifications_Functions.ps1 

#define the SPWebConfigModification constants 
$modificationOwner = "SomeUniqueIdentifier" 
$EnsureChildNode = 0 
$EnsureAttribute = 1 

#get the web configuration modifications xml file 
$webconfigLocation = "C:\PowerShell\WebConfigModifications" 
$webconfigData = $webconfigLocation + "\Web_Config_Modifications.xml" 

# get the Web Application for the given Url 
$url = "http://YOUR-WEB-APP-URL" 
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication $url 
$webapp 
#=============================================================================================================== 

#Write-Host "`nCleaning up existing Nodes" 

#use this statement below to correct for any errors  
#when initially adding new sections / nodes / attributes  
#etc that may cause exceptions 
#$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Clear() 

DeleteSections $webapp $modificationOwner $false 

#=============================================================================================================== 
Write-Host "`nAdding Web Config Nodes" 

#load the xml data 
[xml]$Data = get-content $webconfigData 

foreach ($Section in $Data.Sections.Section) 
{  
    #Ignore sections marked to be skipped 
    if ($Section.Skip -eq "false") 
    { 
        $path = $Section.Path 
        foreach ($modification in $Section.modifications.ChildNodes) 
        { 
            if ($modification.type -eq "EnsureAttribute") 
            { 
                $type = $EnsureAttribute 
                $name = $modification.name 
                  $value =  $modification.value  

                Write-Host "`nChanging $path -> $name to $value" 
            }             
            else 
            { 
                $type = $EnsureChildNode 
                $name = $modification.name 
                $value = "<" + $modification.value + "/>" 

                Write-Host "`nAdding Modifications -> $path : $name, $value" 
            }         

            CreateConfigChildNode $modificationOwner $type $path $name $value 
        } 
    } 
} 

#=============================================================================================================== 
Write-Host "`nApplying Modifications to the Web.Config"         
$webapp.Update() 
$webapp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications() 
Write-Host "`nCompleted Web.Config Modifications" 

#----- END OF FILE  -----# 

#----- START of FUNCTION FILE ----# 

#=================================================================== 
# Web Config Modifications Script Functions 
#=================================================================== 

#=================================================================== 
# function to Create Web Config nodes and or change attributes 
#=================================================================== 
function CreateConfigChildNode($Owner, $Type, $Path, $Name, $Value) 
{ 
    $childNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification  
    $childNode.Owner = $Owner 
    $childNode.Path = $Path 
    $childNode.Name = $Name 
    $childNode.Value = $Value 
    $childNode.Type = $Type 

    $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($childNode) 
} 

#=================================================================== 
# function to remove all existing node and changes to attributes matching the Owner name 
#=================================================================== 
function DeleteSections($webapp, $Owner, $removeOnly) 
{ 
    $count =  $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Count 
    $foundNodes = $false 
    for ($i=$count ;$i -gt -1; $i--) 
    { 
        if ($webapp.WebConfigModifications[$i].Owner -eq $Owner) 
        { 
            $foundNodes = $true 
            Write-Host "`n$i" 
            $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($webapp.WebConfigModifications[$i]) 
        } 
    } 

    if ($foundNodes -and $removeOnly) 
    { 
        $webapp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications() 
        $webapp.Update() 
    } 
} 

#----- END OF FILE  -----#
```

OR

If your SharePoint app has some custom feature then it is best to write web.config settings using `SPWebConfigModification` class of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration` namespace, which allows you to dynamically register entities.

Here is example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help ! I'm going to use SPWebConfigModification ... it looks pretty easy to implement and understandable

Answer (score 2):

What kind of changes do you need to apply to the web.config? SharePoint applications should not store configuration settings in the web.config - it is the least desirable option among the possible ways of storing application settings in SharePoint. Wictor Wilén has a very good post on this topic.

[Six ways to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx)

If you are asking how to apply configuration settings for your SharePoint app then I would strongly recommend to refactor your application to not depend on any settings in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You code web.config changes using the SharePoint API (SPWebConfigModification) and package them into a solution file (.wsp).

Deploy the solution file to the new farm.

Do not modify the web.config file manually.